# What does the Water Barrel do?

Tags: timber-and-stone

As the title says, what is the purpose of the water barrel? Description doesn't explain and the wiki doesn't either, I googled it but didnt find anything helpful.

Comment: I'm wondering myself, self answer if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The water barrel will used by the blacksmith, together with the anvil and the forge, to craft very good armor and weapons.

Comment: well it isnt needed for steel armor or weapons, and thats the best armor and weapons that i've seen. can you maybe add more to this answer, a source would be nice cuz i haven't seen any mention of this.

Comment: I edited to future tense. This is another cause of the game designer putting things into the game that have not been implemented. This is true for putting skeleton and goblin bodies in a catapult, yet there is no catapult as of yet.